# Why is my external script not included and how to change inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, external-script

I am working on a basic website and I'm trying to use JS to make "video-navigator"

The thing is:

- my external script is not being included

So this is my HTML for including my JS

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Click [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYwJmb) for the entire site

Comment: *"i dont know how to use JS to change the HTML"* should we post an entire lesson for you?

Comment: that would be nice, but fine, I'll remove that part

Comment: How do you know it's not loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with this. Firstly you're trying to set the innerHTML incorrectly which is failing. Secondly you're using a **reserved** word for a function (new). In the pop function I've commented out your incorrect bit and added a correct version. I've also renamed your function to new_renamed so that it works.

```
alert("working");
function pop()
{
    alert("INVALID INPUT");
    //HTMLDivElement("content") innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
}
function old()
{
    alert("INVALID INPUT");
}
function new_renamed()
{
    alert("INVALID INPUT");
}
```

Above will log.

Comment: Thank you, the 'new' was the problem. I'll accept your answer in 3 mins, when it lets me